# jQuery removing class from parent div not working

Tags: jquery

does anyone have any ideas why removeClass is not working for me? both removeClass on response and also .required dont work in any instance.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6y4wdf7g/10/

```
if ($(".required").val() === '') {
    $(".required").parent().addClass("has-error");
    $("#response").removeClass("alert-success");
    $("#response").addClass("alert-warning");
    $("#response .message").html("<strong>Error</strong>: It appear's you have forgotten to complete something!");
    $("#response").fadeIn();
} else {
    $(".required").parent().removeClass("has-error");
    // .....
}
```

Comment: please share the html as well or a jsfiddle.

Comment: need html to tell something

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6y4wdf7g/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in looking at the HTML you posted on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6y4wdf7g/10/), I noticed that you have two elements using `id="response"`.  That will cause a problem. The ID is supposed to be unique, and thus only one element should have the same ID.

Technically, the removeClass works.  The problem is your logic.  You are using `$(".required").val() === ''` to check ALL fields, which won't work.  If there is a value in the first `.required` form field and not in any of the rest of the `.required`, the logic will automatically trigger your else clause (because the first iteration of `.required` technically has a value).  If there is NOT a value in the first `.required` form field, it assumes all form fields are empty, and thus the remove class will not work.

If I am understanding things correctly, you will want to do something more like this:

```
var errorCounter = 0;

$(".required").each(function(i, obj) {

    if($(this).val() === ''){
        $(this).parent().addClass("has-error");
        errorCounter++;
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("has-error");
    }

});

if (errorCounter > 0) {
    $("#response").removeClass("alert-success").addClass("alert-warning").fadeIn();
    $("#response .message").html("<strong>Error</strong>: It appear's you have forgotten to complete something!");
}
```

Hope this helps.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have given I would have to guess that either your query is invalid or the class names are not consistent between code and html.